# How can I let the server run my java program?

Tags: java, ssh

I have to log in to a server via SSH and run my java program on a directory that has massive data which is approximately as big as 50GB. From my calculation, running my code on the massive data will take about 6 hours. Is there any way to let the server run my java program so that there won't be any problem running my code even if I get disconnected from the server?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a session in `screen` and run your Java process inside it. Then you can detach it and disconnect your SSH session and rejoin later to check the progress.

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java a wrapper to run your java program like a service if of course it does not need user interaction. This is the way to automate start/stop/ping status of  Batch engines, application servers like JBoss or other.

This is good one that is used in some products http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Answer (score 0):

i recommend that you use screen (see erik ekman), but there is also nohup:

https://serverfault.com/a/76876/181010

Answer (score 0):

start it by `nohup java -jar path/to/your.jar`,
when done kill the process by id.
 or write bash script